# Os.File.setPermission is not recognized as a function

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk, jpm

I have this (partial) main JS code:

```
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm");
[...]
// if it is a Win environment put the attrib file to hidden
OS.File.setPermission(
        OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.homeDir,  'my_file.txt'),
            {
                winAttributes: {
                    hidden: true
                }
            }
).then(x => console.log('success',x), y => console.log('failure',y));
```

I am testing it on Linux, and when the execution reaches the promise indicated above, it is reported this error:

> *console.log: TypeError: OS.File.setPermission is not a function*

I suppose this effect also indicates that the execution of that part on an add-on target Windows platform is compromised, isn't it?

Why does it happen? Where am I wrong? Thanks.

[Here the reference for setPermission](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/OSFile.jsm/OS.File_for_the_main_thread#OS.File.setPermissions)

Comment: Sorry for this post: The question  is very trivial because  it is a matter of distraction, that is, the absence of the 's' in 'Permission'

Comment: So you solved the prblem? :) `OS.File.setPermissions` haha tricky typo it happens